# Laravel 5.2 ajax CSRF

Tags: laravel

I am trying to do a post with ajax to laravel. When using the get method it works fine but with the POST, it fails.

Here is the code:
on my app.blade, I have put:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

on my view.blade, I have the following ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    $('#employeeActivityTable').DataTable( {
        ajax: {
                url: "{!! route('ajaxactivityperemployee') !!}",
                type: "POST"
            },
        columns: [
            { data: 'employee_id', name: 'employee_id' },
            { data: 'employee_name', name: 'employee_name' },
            { data: 'month', name: 'month' },
            { data: 'sum_task_hour', name: 'sum_task_hour' }
            ],
        columnDefs: [
            {
                "targets": [ 0 ],
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": false
            }
            ]
    } );
...
```

I know that my routes are working because I had everything with GET and it worked fine and I only changed it to POST and I get in the troubleshooter tool:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

And here are my routes:

```
//Employee activity
Route::get('employeeactivity', ['uses'=>'EmployeeActivityController@getView','as'=>'employeeactivity']);

//AJAX
//Activity per employee
Route::get('activityperemployee', ['uses'=>'Ajax\ActivityAjaxController@getActivityPerEmployee','as'=>'ajaxactivityperemployee']);
Route::get('activityperproject', ['uses'=>'Ajax\ActivityAjaxController@getActivityPerProject','as'=>'ajaxactivityperproject']);
Route::post('activityperemployee', ['uses'=>'Ajax\ActivityAjaxController@postActivityPerEmployee']);
```

and here is the ajax controller:

```
public function getActivityPerEmployee()
{
    $return = $this->activityRepository->getActivityPerEmployee();
    $data = Datatables::of($return)->make(true);
    return $data;
}
public function postActivityPerEmployee(Request $request)
{
    $where = [['col'=>'employee_id','val'=>'13'],['col'=>'month','val'=>'Jan']];
    $return = $this->activityRepository->getActivityPerEmployee($where);
    $data = Datatables::of($return)->make(true);
    return $data;
}
public function getActivityPerProject()
{
    $return = $this->activityRepository->getActivityPerProject();
    $data = Datatables::of($return)->make(true);
    return $data;
}
```

Again, if in the ajax request, I change the type from POST to GET, everything works fine.

Comment: 500 Error mean that you have a probleme on your server, can you show us your route and controller action ?

Comment: Check the Laravel log for details of the 500 error.

Comment: Maybe you need `as` keys when you are using `uses`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to send a Post request to a Get Route.

`{!! route('ajaxactivityperemployee') !!}"`

Related Route is :

`Route::get('activityperemployee', ['uses'=>'Ajax\ActivityAjaxController@getActivityPerEmployee','as'=>'ajaxactivityperemployee']);`

So in your case you can do somehting like this (give a name to your post route) :

`Route::post('activityperemployee','uses'=>'Ajax\ActivityAjaxController@postActivityPerEmployee', 'as'=>'postajaxactivityperemployee']);`

and then use your new named route in your ajax call :

`{!! route('postajaxactivityperemployee') !!}"`

which will call `postActivityPerEmployee` action